# Merge two Eloquent collections

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I got a setup with an Survey table and each survey have a number of answers (one-to-many) related to itself. I want to make a query to counts the number of answers for each surveyId with parameter1 = 0 and parameter1 = 1 respectively.

I tried to do this:

```
$surveysWithRepliesExposed = Survey::where('title', 'LIKE', "%$name%")
    ->with(array('surveyAnswerSets' => function($query){
        $query->where('parameter1', 0)
        ->selectRaw('surveyId, count(*) as repliesExposed')
        ->groupBy('surveyId');
    }))
    ->select($columns);

$surveysWithRepliesExposed = Survey::where('title', 'LIKE', "%$name%")
    ->with(array('surveyAnswerSets' => function($query){
        $query->where('parameter1', 1)
        ->selectRaw('surveyId, count(*) as repliesControl')
        ->groupBy('surveyId');
    }))
    ->select($columns);
```

But now I get two collections that look almost the same:

```
{
    "surveyId": 11,
    "title": "A survey",
    "startDate": "2015-04-16",
    "endDate": "2015-04-30",
    "survey_answer_sets": [
        {
            "surveyId": 11,
            "repliesExposed": 212
        }
    ]
}
```

And the other

```
{
    "surveyId": 11,
    "title": "A survey",
    "startDate": "2015-04-16",
    "endDate": "2015-04-30",
    "survey_answer_sets": [
        {
            "surveyId": 11,
            "repliesControl": 56
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I merge these so I get

```
{
    "surveyId": 11,
    "title": "A survey",
    "startDate": "2015-04-16",
    "endDate": "2015-04-30",
    "survey_answer_sets": [
        {
            "surveyId": 11,
            "repliesExposed": 212
            "repliesControl": 56
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a little help from a friend.

This code does what I want!

```
$surveys = Survey::leftJoin('SurveyAnswerSets', 'Surveys.surveyId', '=', 'SurveyAnswerSets.surveyId')
    ->select(
        DB::raw(
            "Surveys.surveyId,
           Surveys.title,
           Surveys.startDate,
           Surveys.endDate,
           sum(case when SurveyAnswerSets.isRefGroup = 0 then 1 else 0 end) repliesExposed,
           sum(case when SurveyAnswerSets.isRefGroup = 1 then 1 else 0 end) repliesControl,
           sum(1) repliesTotal"
        )
    )
    ->where('SurveyAnswerSets.isComplete', 1)
    ->where('Surveys.title', 'LIKE', "%$name%")
    ->where('Surveys.isTemplate', 0)
    ->groupBy('Surveys.surveyId')->get();
```